# Print ascending string loop in R

Tags: r

I want to create a simple program that simply prints the phrase "Sample set [number]" repeatedly in a loop, but increasing by 1 each time. For example, the first print will return "Sample set 1" while the next should print "Sample set 2", then "Sample set 3" and so on, all the way until "Sample set 50". I'm new to R and am not sure how to go about doing this, can someone help me out here? This is for a personal project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use R's for-each construct

```
for (num in c(1:50)) {
  paste("sample set", num, sep=" ")
}
```

You'll certainly need to get a handle on loops, but don't neglect learning to reason about your programs using functional techniques. R has a wide range of functionals that with a little effort outperform most loops and are much more elegant